# How to make video by uploading 1 audio file and 1 to 10 images using ffmpeg

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

In my local environment i use ffmpeg library to make video  on windows
it works fine by command line as well as by using php exec command.
But when testing on **live server** It not works fine.I configured ffmpeg on my server and test but php exec command not work and there is no error.
**Is there is any way that we use or upload ffmpeg library in live website folder and give proper path in php exec command.**

Comment: could you post  `exec` code

Comment: Hope this link will help https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP in using ffmpeg library via git cloning

Comment: <?php


 $command="/usr/bin/ffmpeg   -framerate 1/60  -i foo-%03d.jpg -i song.mp3  -c:a copy   result9.avi";

 
    $re = exec($command);
   
die("<b>Command executed successfully. </b>");?>

Comment: In project folder images like foo-001.jpg and foo-002.jpg and audio song.mp3 available.